# Area under the graph through integration

Tags: calculus, integration

For the shaded region.

Why must I integrate from the $y$ axis ? From $\frac{1}{3}$ to $3$

Why I can't integrate from the $x$ axis ? 
From $-7$ to $2$

[image]

Comment: You would need to split your $x$ axis integral in two, one from -7 to 17/9, and from 17/9 to 2, since the formula for the $y$ differs. But you can do it if you want to

Answer (score 2):

You can if you'd like.  However, notice that for the region between $x=\frac{17}{9}$ and $x=2$, you would not be integrating from the line up to the curve - instead, you'd be integrating from part of the curve to itself.

The integral would take the following form:

$$I = \int_{-7}^{17/9}\left( \sqrt{2-x}-\frac{3}{8}(1-x)\right) dx + \int_{17/9}^2 \left(\sqrt{2-x}-(-\sqrt{2-x})\right) dx$$

This is somewhat more annoying than integrating along the y-axis, which would require no such splitting:

$$ I = \int_{-1/3}^3\left(2-y^2 -(1-\frac{8}{3}y)\right) dy $$

But you can check to see that both integrals yield the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's just
$$-\int\limits_{-\frac{1}{3}}^3\left(1-\frac{8x}{3}-(2-x^2)\right)dx$$
There is a minus before the integral because the orientation changed.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question it's because when $x\geq 17/9$ the parabolic portion $x=2-y^2$ of the boundary fails the vertical line test, which means it is not a function of $x$ there. Notice that the Riemann Sum requires that the function supply the value that will be multiplied by length of the partition which will then be taken to the limit, but on this region since it's not a function the choice of value is ambiguous because there can be multiple $y$ values for each $x$.

This problem is removed however if we instead integrate by $y$ on the region where on that axis it is in fact a function. The easiest way to see this is to swap all the $x$ and $y$ variables in the equations, plot the graph and see that both the linear and parabolic limits are functions of $y$. Visually, this amounts to reflecting the graphs about the line $y=x$. Now the problem is removed entirely and it's business as usual.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand why you can integrate over either $x$ or $y$ it's wise to keep in mind that the area is properly defined as

$$A=\int\!\!\!\int dx~dy=\int y~dx=\int x~dy$$